# React routing to anther page when load successfully

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a several page react website. In page A, the user clicks a button that retrieves some contents in firebase. I would like to go to page B only if the retrieval is successful and pass the retrieved content as well.

Here is the router to pageB where ciphertext and plaintext are set to null unless the content is retrieved from Firebase.

```
<Route path={`${path}/pageB`}>
  <NewContent props={[ciphertext, plaintext]}/>
</Route>
```

Here is the "next" button that will lead to pageB if getStatus from firebase is successful.

```
{
    getStatus === 3 &&
    <Link to={`${path}/pageB`} className='button'> 
      Next 
    </Link>
}
```

Currently, there is a "load" button and when loaded successfully, a "next" button will show up to go to the next page. I would like to remove the next button and go to the second page directly when loaded to make it more intuitive. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

{
    getStatus === 3 &&
    <Redirect to={`${path}/pageB`}/> 
}
```